# Difference between bottom and top dynamo/motor in a dot matrix printer

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller

What is the difference between bottom and top dynamo/motor in Canon or other dot matrix printer (I'm only aware of one whose job is moving carriage left-right back and forth) ?

Which one should be designed with greater torque but less RPM, and which one vice-versa of that ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a motor to move the paper in up/down direction?

Comment: Dynamos are DC generators. Printers do not generate electrical power.

Comment: I have disassembled a lot of dot matrix printers and I don't remember any having a 'bottom' and 'top' motor. Which printer models are you looking at?

Comment: One drives eff eye eff and da udder only goes up